# Typescript cannot read property target of undefined onDocumentClick

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

*I am new to Typescript, as trying to use Angular. I am rewriting my project to angular system. And I have encountered a problem. I want to remove the dropdown content when the user clicks anywhere except the dropdown button. Please help this beginner, i have been googling but found nothing. Thanks a lot!*

**DETAILS**

These are in the app.component

app.component.html

```
<section class="nav">
  <div class="one-side-nav">
      <a href="#" routerLink = "/"><img id="logo" src="assets/img/logoheaven.png"></a>
      <a href="#" routerLink = "/catalog" id="framed">SOMETHING</a>
  </div>
  <div class="one-side-nav">
      <a href="">SOMTHING</a>
      <a href="">SOMETHING</a>
      <a href=""><img src="assets/img/lists/notification.png"></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <img (click)="dropdown()" class="dropdown-btn" id = "dropdown-btn" src="assets/img/defaultimg.png">
          <div id="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
              <div class="box-head-blue"></div>
              <a href="#">dropdown</a>
              <a href="#">dropdown</a>
              <a href="#">dropdown</a>
              <button style="border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px" id="logout-btn">dropdown</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

//COMPONENT LOGIC
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'SPARK | Trang Chủ';

  dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$events'])
  onDocumentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!(event.target == document.getElementById("dropdown-btn"))) {
      var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
      if (dropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
          dropdown.classList.remove("show");
      }
    }
  }

}
```

ERROR IM GETTING

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
>     at AppComponent.onDocumentClick (app.component.ts:19)
>     at AppComponent_click_HostBindingHandler (app.component.ts:10)
>     at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21815)
>     at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21857)
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:976)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41640)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
>     at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
> ```

HOW I HAVE IT IN JAVASCRIPT (works)

```
function dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches(".dropdown-btn")) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
        if (dropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
            dropdown.classList.remove("show");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $event not $events.

**Try this:**

```
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  onDocumentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (!(event.target == document.getElementById("dropdown-btn"))) {
      var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
      if (dropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
          dropdown.classList.remove("show");
      }
    }
  }
```